# Why does bit shifting with equal sign prints out different result opposed to non-equal case?

Tags: c, hex, bit-shift, byte-shifting

Why are 01 and 02 case different?

```
char c=0xAB;
printf("01:%x\n", c<<2); // fffffeac
printf("02:%x\n", c<<=2); //ffffffac
printf("03:%x\n", c<<=2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit promotions.

You are on a system that uses [twos complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for representing data in native machine format, `char` is signed and has 8 bits and `int` has 32 bits on your machine.

The `c` and `2` in `c<<2` are [implicitly promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) to `int`, so it becomes `(int)c << (int)2`. `c` is `0xAB`, `(int)c` is [sign-extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Sign_extension) to 32 bits so it is `0xffffffab`. Then `<<2` happens so the resulting value is `0xfffffeac`.

The `c <<= 2` stores the value of `0xfffffeac` inside `c` first, then the value of the whole expression becomes the value of `c` after the assignment. So the result of `c << 2` being `(int)0xfffffeac` is converted to `char` on assignment to `c`. Because `char` has 8 bits on your machine, the value is truncated to 8 bits and `c` becomes equal to `0xac`. Then again, [default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) happen for [each argument that is a part of the variable argument list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic) in a variable argument function call, like `printf(const char *, ...);` - each argument after `..` undergoes default argument promotions. So then `c` now beeing equal to `0xac` is again sign-extended to 32 bits to `int`, so becomes `0xffffffac`.